# Sum odd numbers from a given range[a,b]?

Tags: java

I was practicing with some exercises from UVA Online Judge, I tried to do the Odd sum which basically is given a range[a,b], calcule the sum of all odd numbers from a to b.

I wrote the code but for some reason I don't understand I'm getting 891896832 as result when the range is [1,2] and based on the algorithm it should be 1, isn't it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OddSum 
{
    static Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int T = teclado.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[T];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Case "+(i+1)+": "+sum());
        }
    }
    public static int sum()
    {
        int a=teclado.nextInt();
        int b = teclado.nextInt();
        int array[] = new int[1000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {   
            if(a%2!=0)
            {               
                array[i]=a;
                if(array[i]==(b))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }   
            a++;    
        }
        int res=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if(array[i]==1 && array[2]==0)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            else
            {
            res = res + array[i];
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get 891896832, then based on your algorithm, it should be 891896832. Computers don't make mistakes (unless programmed to).

Comment: To follow up on what @immibis is saying: study the flow of your program. Don't guess, debug. Sidenote: snippets are for HTML etc, so you might want to re-format your code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it as simple as possible by simply keeping track of the sum along the way, as opposed to storing anything in an array.  Use a for-loop and add the index to the sum if the index is an odd number:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter minimum range value: ");
    int min = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter maximum range value: ");
    int max = keyboard.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = min; i < max; i++) {
        if(i % 2 != 0) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The sum of the odd numbers from " + min + " to " + max + " are " +  sum);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will do it in a simpler way, do you have any idea why am I getting 891896832 as result in the [1,2] range?

Comment: See my answer for the reason: you are only checking your condition when the high end is odd. Therefore, you are filling up your entire array and then summing all the values, resulting in that ridiculous number.

Answer (score 3):

Your stopping condition is only ever checked when your interval's high end is odd.

Move

```
if (array[i] == (b)) {
    break;
}
```

out of the `if(a % 2 != 0)` clause.

In general, I don't think you need an array, just sum the odd values in your loop instead of adding them to the array.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Java installed right now, however a simple C# equivalent is as follows: (assign any values in a and b)

```
        int a = 0;
        int b = 10;
        int result = 0;
        for (int counter = a; counter <= b; counter++)
        {
            if ((counter % 2) != 0) // is odd
            {
                result += counter;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum: " + result);
```

No major dramas, simple n clean.